# jQuery popup box stacking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

So basically, I have a function that shows a popup over the browser window. I need to call it twice consecutively. How can I call the same function a second time and have it only run once the first window has been dismissed?

```
function focusbox() {
   $("#box").show();
}

$("#close-focus").live("click", function() {
   $("#box").fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function as the call back of fade out?

```
$("#close-focus").live("click", function() {
   $("#box").fadeOut(function() {
      focusbox(); //add your parameters in here
   });
});
```

Comment: So I tried this, but the function has been called with other variables sent to it, so I need to somehow allow the secondary execution to come through (because it does a different thing)

Comment: @Sneaksta updated my answer, If you need any more information you may need to show more code :)

Comment: Okay I might do that. Curious though, what does adding the function() {} do?

Comment: You are basically defining a anonymous function to be used when fadeOut is completed, it is just like any other function except is has no reference. Now we are putting the call to your focusBox function inside an anon one so we can add the parameters :)